# Scala Future - beginner query

Tags: multithreading, scala

The following code does what is expected.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

object UseFuture extends App 
{
  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global
  Future(println { "This should be run in another thread" })
  println("Test")
}
```

But I'm not able to see the output of the Future in.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

object UseFuture extends App 
{
  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global
  Future(println { "This should be run in another thread" })
 }
```

A quick explanation?

Comment: Maybe your program finished before the Future got scheduled? Try to add a `Thread.sleep` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Thilo is right, your app is exited faster than Future starts executing.
Basically, using Await.result is not good practice [when you work with Future](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/4-concurrency-parallelism.md#45-should-not-block), so this example only for education purpose :)

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object UseFuture extends App
{
  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global
  println(s"Current thread: ${Thread.currentThread().getId}")
  val future = Future(println { s"Thread id in future: ${Thread.currentThread().getId}. This should be run in another thread" })

  Await.result(future, 15.seconds)
  println("Future has been executed")
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. I think in Java the program exits after all threads are done unless we call System.exit(). Is there anything like that possible here?

Comment: Future is a placeholder for value which not yet exists, println is a side-effecting function, so Await still does not need to wait for result and program still can end faster than displaying println string.

Comment: @RasterR, Scala is compiled to JVM bytecode, so the rules should be the same. JVM exits the program if the main thread is finished and there are no others non-daemon threads (user threads).

Comment: @Emilia, have not got your point. What's that got to do with side effects? If you get the type of val future, it will show you Future[Unit]. Yes. println is side-effect and its type is Unit, but main thread will be blocked until future completed or timed-out due to 15 seconds duration.

Comment: In java this code does not exit till the thread is run.
public class UseRunnableNewStyle {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Runnable r = () -> System.out.println("This should be run in another thread");
  new Thread(r).start();
 }
}

Maybe the issue is we are using Future and not Thread?

Comment: @RasterR, I've mentioned it already. Create it as a daemon thread and it will exit ;)

Comment: So can the future be a non-daemon thread?. Anyways I got your point."The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads."

Comment: Future != Thread. Future is a concept. It can run in a thread pool, or in a new thread every time. You can create your own [ExecutionContext](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/ExecutionContext.html), when all your threads will be non-daemon